# how to save only updated row in jsp to sql

Tags: jsp, servlets

is there a way to check whether a row is updated in jsp and only save the row that is updated to database without having to save the whole data again?

the following is a part of my code in JSP:

```
<% 
DetailsMod bean = null;
List resultList = (List) session.getAttribute("list");
int count1=-1;
String value2 = "";
  if(resultList.size() > 0 )  {  
  int rowNum = 1;
   for(int i=0; i<resultList.size(); i++){
    bean = (DetailsMod) resultList.get(i);
%>
<input type="text" name="tbx_cost1"/>

<input type="text" name="tbx_cost2"/>

<% count1 = i;
}
}%>
```

and this is a part of my code in servlet

```
if(cost.size()>0){
  for(int i=0; i<cost.size(); i++){
      costCodeDetailsMod = (ShsCostCodeDetailsMod) cost.get(i);
      String cost1= RutString.getParameterToString(request, "tbx_cost1" + i);
      String cost2= RutString.getParameterToString(request, "tbx_cost2" + i);
  }
}
```

so lets say resultList = 4 so there will be 4 rows of tbx_cost1 and tbx_cost2. so lets say I only edit the values of the first row and keep the rest of the rows values the same. is there a way for me to save only the updated row to the servlet which will then be saved to the database?
Thanks in advance for any possible help.

Comment: When a row is selected to edit/update, does that row had a unique id? If so get the row id and pass those values to database.

Comment: before this page there is a page where user select an option, when selected it will come to this page and display all the rows using for loop as above(all of this row have a unique identifier).I do not have a checkbox to check which row have been updated so is there a way to identify the updated row without the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the quest again i felt so dumb... I could just set the condition in my sql statement to update only the rows that have been changed.

Anyways, thanks for the help @Polppan. you gave me the idea :D